# Metaclasses and methods

Tags: python, metaprogramming, self, metaclass

Adding a method to metaclass works perfectly in the below example.

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def double(self):
        return self.x*2

# method to add
def quadruple(self):
    return self.x*4

# creating metaclass
TypeTest = type('TypeTest', (Test,), {'triple': triple, 
                                      'quadruple': quadruple})

# prints 8
TypeTest(2).quadruple()
```

The below example doesn't work and I have no idea why. It simply doesn't recognise self in the parsed function and a TypeError occurs.

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, wheels, door=False):
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.door = door

# method to add
def check_load(self, x):
    if x > self.load:
        return "Load won't fit"
    else:
        return "Load will fit"

# creating metaclass
Truck = type('Truck', (Vehicle,), dict(wheels=4,door=True, load=100,
                                       check_load=check_load))

# TypeError: check_load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
Truck.check_load(10)
```

Comment: You are not creating a metaclass. You are *using* the `type` metaclass to produce a regular class.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: "Adding a method to metaclass works perfectly in the below example." That's impossible because the name `triple` isn't bound to anything, so the reference to it throws a `NameError`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: You are *not* creating a metaclass, you are creating regular classes. `type()` is the (base) metaclass here, calling it creates a new class object (the same type of object that a `class` statement produces).

The first `type()` call is essentially equivalent to:

```
class TypeTest(Test)
    triple = triple
    quadruple = quadruple
```

and the second example is the same as:

```
class Truck(Vehicle)
    wheels = 4
    door = True
    load = 100
    check_load = check_load
```

You forgot to create an *instance* of your `Truck` class:

```
Truck.check_load(10)
```

This leaves the `check_load()` function with nothing to bind to, there is no `self`.

In your first example you *did* create an instance:

```
TypeTest(2).quadruple()
```

Notice the call, passing in `2`.

Create an instance for `self` to be bound to:

```
Truck(4, True).check_load(10)
```

If you wanted your class to not need arguments to create an instance, you'll need to provide a different `__init__` method too, one that overrides the `Vehicle.__init__` method:

```
def init(self): pass

Truck = type('Truck', (Vehicle,), dict(
    wheels=4,door=True, load=100,
    check_load=check_load, __init__=init))
```

Now you can create the instance without arguments:

```
Truck().check_load(10)
```